# Cant get memcache to work using xampp/php

Tags: php, memcached, xampp

Im on Windows 7, 64/bit running xampp v3.1. The php version is 5.4, Im trying to install memcache locally on the box so I can use memcache with php. I have searched google and followed directions about installing memcached.exe as a service, then downloading the memcache dll extension file for php and putting it into the ext folder under the php folder. I then add it to the php.ini folder, restart apache and memcache does not show up when running phpinfo() and when I try to run memcache via php it tells me this function does not exist. Can anyone help me figure this out? I verified the service is up and running, I tried different versions of the dll php extension file but still same issue. Any suggestions? Here is one site I used for instructions on installing memcache:

http://shikii.net/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I grabbed the incorrect version of memcache for php. You must grab the correct memcache dll file for the php version you are using. I found the correct download here:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/memcache/3.0.6/php_memcache-3.0.6-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip

It has the correct php version, 5.4 and its thread safe. Once I downloaded it, extracted the dll and put into php extension folder and restarted xampp/apache, it now works.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some error logged into your apache logs. What is the error?

Comment: I looked through the logs and no errors found except Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]